# HTML5 canvas clearRect count remaining pixel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I remove some pixel with `clearRect` on mouse move on my 200x200px canvas element.
Now, I would like to check if there are no pixels left to remove (all 40.000px are removed), then reset or load a new image.

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  x = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  y = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;
  context.clearRect(x, y, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: What did you try ? was a question once asked when question quality did matter.

Comment: @GameAlchemist in case you didn't notice, the problem has already been solved. I recommend you read this btw: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to detect if the canvas is blank:

### Compare data-uris

Initially grab a string from the blank canvas before starting to draw to it. If you change the size of the canvas you also need to update this string.

```
var blankCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/bmp');
```

This will get a BMP (uncompressed) image in browsers which support this format, or default to PNG if not. Obtaining an uncompressed image will increase memory use but also performance when obtaining the string (but slow down when comparing it, if large).

Then do the same when you want to compare:

```
var currentCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/bmp');

if (currentCanvas === blankCanvas) {
    /* it's empty */
}
```

### Compare pixels

The only way is to iterate through the pixels to see if all the values are black transparent.

Here is one way: call this method every time you need to check (typically on mouseup event) -

```
function hasPixels() {

    var idata = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
        buffer = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),  // use 32-bit buffer
        len = buffer.length,
        i;

    for(; i < len; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] !== 0) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will return true if there are any pixels remaining on canvas.

The 32-bit buffer allows us to check one complete pixel at the time and will perform better that comparing each component.

### Notes

Both approaches require [CORS requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) in relation to the images be fulfilled for this to work. This is a security mechanism in browsers preventing extraction of pixels from canvas cross-origin.

Which approach is faster depends on various factors such as the size of the canvas, browser implementation and so forth. You would need to check for your scenario. I would perhaps add a coin to the second solution for general usage together with the benefit of low resource consumption. But for a 200x200 canvas both should work well.